# Correct code to remove the vowels from a string in Python

Tags: python

I'm pretty sure my code is correct but it doesn't seem to returning the expected output:

input `anti_vowel("Hey look words")`  --> outputs: `"Hey lk wrds"`.

Apparently it's not working on the `'e'`, can anyone explain why?

```
def anti_vowel(c):
    newstr = ""
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for x in c.lower():
        if x in vowels:
            newstr = c.replace(x, "")        
    return newstr
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The function [`str.replace(old, new[, max])`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) don't changes `c` string itself (wrt to `c` you calls) just returns a new string which the occurrences of old have been replaced with new. So `newstr` just contains a string replaced by last vowel in `c` string that is the `o` and hence you are getting `"Hey lk wrds"` that is same as `"Hey look words".replace('o', '')`.

I think you can simply write `anti_vowel(c)` as:

```
''.join([l for l in c if l not in vowels]);
```

What I am doing is iterating over string and if a letter is not a vowel then only include it into list(filters). After filtering I join back list as a string.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[l for l in c if l not in vowels]`?

Comment: You can leave out the [] and use the implicit Generator instead of this intermediate List.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024 for a `''.join()` call it is faster to use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan :-) I was just in the process of timeit'ing it

Comment: A programming newbie here. Could you guys pls explain to me this way expression: "[l for l in c if l not in vowels]" ? I know about for loops,if etc. but how could u pull this one out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IlianVasilevKulishev the expression `[l for l in c if l not in vowels]` known [list compression](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: this also has an issue with case, but great solution

Comment: @Jon `vowels` can be assigned `'aeiouAEIOU'` or better `frozenset('aeiouAEIOU')`  for case

Answer (score 16):

Why don't you do it with regexp? According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), something like this should work:

```
import re

def anti_vowel(s):
    result = re.sub(r'[AEIOU]', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return result
```

If you're using the function often, you could compile the regexp and use the compiled version.

Comment: This seem like the best approach to me (only commenting because of the errent down vote)

Answer (score 11):

Try String.translate.

```
>>> "Hey look words".translate(None, 'aeiouAEIOU')
'Hy lk wrds'
```

> string.translate(s, table[, deletechars])
>
> Delete all characters from s that are in deletechars (if present), and then translate the characters using table, which must be a 256-character string giving the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal. If table is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template.substitute

Or if you're using the newfangled Python 3:

```
>>> table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('aeiouAEIOU'))
>>> "Hey look words.translate(table)
'Hy lk wrds'
```

Comment: This is best way I think, I prefer to use tools provided by language over writing a new.

Comment: Nice, but this doesn't work in Python3.  `'test'.translate(str.maketrans('aeiouAEIOU', '-'*10))` produces `t-st`,  but can't replace with None in Python 3

Comment: Updated for Python 3. Agree that it's slightly more awkward.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to forego the vowel variable and put the char's to remove in the loop.

```
    def anti_vowel(text):
        for i in "aeiouAEIOU":
            text = text.replace(i,"")
        return text

    print anti_vowel("HappIEAOy")
```

Answer (score 5):

You should do this:

initialize `newstr` to `c`, and then

```
for x in c.lower():
    if x in vowels:
        newstr = newstr.replace(x, "")
```

That's because `str.replace(old, new[, max])` returns the a copy of the string after replacing the characters:

> The method replace() returns a copy of the string in which the
>   occurrences of old have been replaced with new, optionally restricting
>   the number of replacements to max.

So, this is the correct code:

```
def anti_vowel(c):
    newstr = c
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for x in c.lower():
        if x in vowels:
            newstr = newstr.replace(x,"")

    return newstr
```

You can also do it in a more pythonic way:

```
''.join([x for x in c if x not in vowels])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'O', 'U')

for char in text:

    if char in vowels:

        text = text.replace(char, '')

return text
```

Comment: This is really interesting! One of the simplest I guess for a new comer.

Comment: The only issue for me personally, is that when I try to do that not in a function, and not with "return", then I get the word repeated over and over again until it has no vowels...while I would rather get the result directly.

Answer (score 3):

One more simpler way can be extracting the non-vowel characters from string and returning them.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    newstring=""
    for i in text:
        if i not in "aeiouAEIOU":
            newstring=newstring+i
    text=newstring
    return text
```

Comment: one thing, you can return newstring instead of text

Answer (score 3):

I know there are many correct solutions on this subject but I thought to add few fun ways of solving this problem.
If you come from a C++/C# or Java, you will tend to use something like compare then action using the index to remove the unwanted entry in a for loop. Python has the Remove and Del functions. Remove function uses the value and 
del uses the index.The pythonic solution is in the last function. Lets see how we can do that:

**Here we are using the index in a for loop and del function very similar in C++:**

```
def remove_vol(str1):
     #list2 = list1 # this won't work bc list1 is the same as list2 meaning same container#
    list1 = list(str1)
    list2 = list(str1)
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[i] in volwes:
            vol = list1[i]
            x = list2.index(vol)
            del list2[x]
    print(list2)
```

**Using the remove function:**

```
def remove_vol(str1): 
      list1 = list(str1)
      list2 = list(str1)
      for i in list1:
          if i in volwes:
              list2.remove(i)
      print(list2)
```

**Building new string that does not contain the unwanted chars using their indexes:**

```
def remove_vol(str1):  
    list1 = list(str1)
    clean_str = ''
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[i] not in volwes:
            clean_str += ''.join(list1[i])
    print(clean_str)
```

**Same as in the solution in above but using the value:**

```
def remove_vol(str1):
    list1 = list(str1)
    clean_str = ''
    for i in list1:
        if i not in volwes:
            clean_str += ''.join(i)
    print(clean_str)
```

**How you should do it in python? Using list comprehension! It is beautiful:**

```
def remove_vol(list1):
    clean_str = ''.join([x for x in list1 if x.lower() not in volwes])
    print(clean_str)
```

Comment: The method with the remove function is really interesting!

Answer (score 2):

```
def anti_vowel(text):
new=[]
vowels = ("aeiouAEIOU")
for i in text:
    if i not in vowels:
        new.append(i)
return ''.join(new)
```

i hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

```
def anti_vowel(text):
  new_text = ""
  for i in text:
    if i == 'a' or i == 'A':
      pass
    elif i == 'e' or i == 'E':
      pass
    elif i == 'I' or i == 'i':
      pass
    elif i == 'o' or i == 'O':
      pass
    elif i == 'u' or i == 'U':
      pass
    else:
      new_text = new_text + i
  return new_text

print anti_vowel('Hey look Words!')
```

Answer (score 1):

My implementation:

---

```
# Ask the user for input:
user_input = input("enter a string with some vowels: ")
print("input string: " + str(user_input))
vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')
new_string="";
for i in range(0,len(user_input),1):
    if user_input[i] in vowels:
        print ('found a vowel, removing...')
    else:
        new_string+=user_input[i]
print("I've removed the vowels for you. You're welcome! The new string is: " + new_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple approach could be;

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    t = ''
    for c in text:
        if c in "aeiouAEIOU":
            pass
    else:  
        t += c  
    return t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    t=""
    for c in text:
        for i in "ieaouIEAOU":
            if c==i:
                c=""
            else:
                c=c
        t=t+c
    return t
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.