# cant get script to just remove vowels from the input labeled twittr

Tags: python

I've got an input "twittr" and a List of all the vowels, and i'm trying to get the script to remove the vowes from the input twittr.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuKdT.png)

I'm not too sure what to try at this point.

Comment: always share your code as text and not as images

Comment: `for list in twittr` will just loop over string chars.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image. Post the code as plain text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581824/correct-code-to-remove-the-vowels-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
twittr = input("Input : ")

vowels  = ['a','e','i','o','u']

for letter in twittr:
    if letter in vowels :
        twittr = twittr.replace(letter,"")
    

print(twittr)
```