# Iterate over a input string, if a vowel: remove - but how to make the .replace case sensitive so I don't have to include caps in the list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, input, replace

```
def main():

    x = input("Input: ")

    convert(x)

def convert(a):
    #for loop over array of a e i o u
    v = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']

    for x in v:
        if x in a:
            a = a.replace(x, "")
    print(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This works fine but I want to make it more succinct. There surely is a way to ingnore case in the .replace

Comment: code review SE would be a better place to ask if the code works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct code to remove the vowels from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581824/correct-code-to-remove-the-vowels-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions like `.lower()` and `.upper()` to handle such situations. For example, here you can make this small change  `x = input("Input: ").lower()` and `v = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']`.

and it will work.